# Master-Detail-View: jump between views

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

[shortened version]

I need help with navigation between views. I've done my homework and found out that this can be achieved with a boolean variable that has a read/write binding to isActive. But it just doesn't work so far.

Below are excerpts from the code. On the top-level view, it displays a list of persons for each of which there is a navigation link that is used to edit the persons properties.

Currently I have two other views to manage the list: ClearList and NewPerson. I have embedded both as further navigation links.

What I want to achieve now is that when the button in ClearList ist pressed, the view automatically changes to NewPerson.

Below is one of several attempts that didn't work. I included the boolean variable in AppState in order to access it from all views, but nothing happens when it is changed.

Again, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    var name: String
}

class AppState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var activeIds : [Int] = [0,1]
    @Published var persons: [Person] = [Person(id: 0, name: "Dummy1"),
                                    Person(id: 1, name: "Dummy2"),
                                    Person(id: 2, name: "Dummy3")]
    
    @Published var newPersonViewActive: Bool = false // by setting this variable to true,
                                                     // I want to switch to the newPerson view.
                                                     // Doesn't work so far... 

    var activePersons : [Person] {
        return activeIds.compactMap { id in
            persons.first(where: { $0.id == id
            })
        }
    }
        
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var state = AppState()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ClearList(state: state)
                        label: {Text("clear list")}
                    )
                    ForEach(state.activePersons, id: \.self) { person in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: EditPerson(person: state.bindingForId(id: person.id)),
                            label: {
                                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(person.name)
                                        .font(.system(size: 26, weight: .regular))
                         
                                }.padding(15)
                            })
                    }
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: NewPerson(state: state),
                        isActive: $state.newPersonViewActive,
                        label: {Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")})
                }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 30)
                .navigationTitle("Participants")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                Text("Planning")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EditPerson : View {
    
    // manage the current order of a particular person

    }
}

struct ClearList : View {
    @ObservedObject var state : AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            state.activePersonsIds = []
            state.newPersonViewActive = true // I thought this would make the
                                             // newPerson view active.
                                             // It doesn't...

    }
}

struct NewPerson: View {
    @ObservedObject var state : AppState
    var body: some View {

// add a new person
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for somebody to write the code for you? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: No, I don't want any more help than anybody else here. I just need advice with this .isActive thing that isn't working.

In what way should I have asked for help? Should I post the code of the attempts that failed? Should I have provided less background? Of course, it wasn't necessary for me to describe my project. Do you think it is more appropriate for SO to provide only as much information as needed?

Comment: You should look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.  Remove all the unnecessary code read what a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is when you have a clear plan we can try to help you sort the kinks but as it stands you  are asking for everything to be written for you in order for us to provide an acceptable answer.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've begun to shorten the code. I'll finish later.

Comment: I have shortened the code and included one of the many version I tried that didn't work. Hope that is OK.

Comment: Your code is still not a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) anybody should be able to copy and paste your code and be able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the clear button a `NavigationLink` that goes to a page with another button to clear, it seems like what you want is to just have a non-NavigationLink button that clears the list and push the `NewPerson` view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var state = AppState()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    Button(action: { //<-- Here
                        state.activeIds = []
                        state.newPersonViewActive = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Clear")
                    }
                    ForEach(state.activePersons, id: \.self) { person in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: EditPerson(person: state.bindingForId(id: person.id)),
                            label: {
                                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(person.name)
                                        .font(.system(size: 26, weight: .regular))
                                    
                                }.padding(15)
                            })
                    }
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: NewPerson(state: state),
                        isActive: $state.newPersonViewActive,
                        label: {Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")})
                }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 30)
                .navigationTitle("Participants")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                Text("Planning")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    var name: String
}

class AppState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var activeIds : [Int] = [0,1]
    @Published var persons: [Person] = [Person(id: 0, name: "Dummy1"),
                                        Person(id: 1, name: "Dummy2"),
                                        Person(id: 2, name: "Dummy3")]
    
    @Published var newPersonViewActive: Bool = false
    
    var activePersons : [Person] {
        return activeIds.compactMap { id in
            persons.first(where: { $0.id == id
            })
        }
    }
    
    func bindingForId(id: Int) -> Binding<Person> {
        .init { () -> Person in
            self.persons.first(where: { $0.id == id }) ?? Person(id: -1, name: "()")
        } set: { (newValue) in
            self.persons = self.persons.map {
                if $0.id == id {
                    return newValue
                } else {
                    return $0
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct EditPerson : View {
    @Binding var person : Person
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Edit")
    }
}

struct NewPerson: View {
    @ObservedObject var state : AppState
    var body: some View {
        Text("New person")
    }
}
```

---

**Update, based on comments**

I would strongly recommend against doing this, as it's not a good UX experience. Use an Alert or ActionSheet to confirm the action instead.

```
struct ClearList : View {
    @ObservedObject var state : AppState
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            state.activeIds = []
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                state.newPersonViewActive = true
            }
        }) {
            Text("Clear")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this would be the most straightforward solution. However, I want to prevent the user from inadvertently clicking "clear" and navigation link was one way to do this.

Comment: The normal way to achieve this is through an `Alert` or `ActionSheet` that allows them to confirm their choice.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include what you seem to be asking for. I would recommend against using that option, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found a solution that works as originally intended: apparently "onDisappear{state.newPersonViewActive = true}" (as suggested by lorem ipsum, thanks BTW) can be combined with ".dismiss()":

```
struct ClearList: View {
    @ObservedObject var state : AppState
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            state.activeIds.removeAll()
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()     //  <---       
        }) {
            Text("clear list")
        }.onDisappear{state.newPersonViewActive = true}      //  <---
    }
```